# Gogs Security INSTALL_LOCK Parameter

Tags: git, gogs

In the gogs `app.ini` configuration file I see that there is an `INSTALL_LOCK` configuration parameter.  What is this parameter for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **[the docs](https://gogs.io/docs/advanced/configuration_cheat_sheet#security-(security))** (which I found by searching Google for your title, "Gogs Security INSTALL_LOCK Parameter"):

> `INSTALL_LOCK`: Indicates whether to allow the open install page (setting admin account is involved, so it’s a very important value).

Comment: Thanks - I found that as well, but was not quite sure exactly how it worked, so I ended up testing it out, and figured I would just share the result.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Gogs app.ini cheatsheet](https://gogs.io/docs/advanced/configuration_cheat_sheet):

```
INSTALL_LOCK: Indicates whether to allow the open install page (setting admin account is involved, so it’s a very important value).
```

So after your first install Gogs sets this value to true in order to prevent the open install page from opening again on restart Gogs.  If you reset it to false, then the `open install page` will reopen with your current settings.  Once you click install your configuration settings will be updated.